# How can I have a JScrollPane fill the height of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist

I'm starting with Java and Swing, so I have a very simple question but I just can't find any (simple) way to solve it...

What I mean is just have a list scroller that occupy the whole height of a panel, nothing more. Here is the code I already wrote, thanx to help me to find a way to achieve my goal:

```
public class TestCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setSize(300, 300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panelUp = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelDown = new JPanel();

    window.add(panelUp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    window.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.WEST);
    window.add(panelDown, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    panelUp.setBackground(new Color(200, 240, 200));
    panelCenter.setBackground(new Color(240, 200, 200));
    panelDown.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 240));

    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.addElement("Element 1");
    v.addElement("Element 2");
    v.addElement("Element 3");
    v.addElement("Element 4");
    v.addElement("Element 5");
    v.addElement("Element 6");

    JList list = new JList(v);
    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);

    panelCenter.add(listScroller);

    window.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: If you want to use `BorderLayout` you will first have to set the layout to `BorderLayout`. Try `window.setLayout(...)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default layout for a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout`, for a control to be centered and fill a JPanel you need to use the `BorderLayout`.  Try this:

```
panelCenter.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panelCenter.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you Nick, that's exactly what I needed. Sorry that was pretty simple but I'm not familiar at all with layout in Java.

By the way, **panelCenter.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER)** is pretty useless, everything works fine without

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need `panelCenter`, just add `listScroller` directly to the root pane, using `window.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER)`. It's important to use `CENTER` if you want to fill the entire space of a component with `BorderLayout`. See [the tutorial on BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more info.

If you want to keep `panelCenter`, make sure you explicitly give it a `BorderLayout`. The default layout for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.

I would use:

```
JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```